# Determine, whether the following sets together with the mappings are groups or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm a newbie in groups and currently working on some exercises to get familiar with the material. I have to determine, whether the following sets together with the mappings are groups or not. I have the following solutions to the following problems:

**Solved Problem 1**

$\Bbb{Z}$  with  $(x,y)\mapsto x+y-2$

This is a group, since it is associative, has an identity element $e=2$, such that $x+2-2=x$, and has an inverse element $x^{-1}=x-4$, such that $x+x-4-2=e$.

**Solved Problem 2**

$\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$  with  $(x,y)\mapsto {x\over y}$

This is a group, since it is associative, has an identity element $e=1$, such that ${x\over1}=x$, and has an inverse element $y=x$ for every $x$ in $\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$, such that ${x\over y}=e$.

**Unsolved Problems 3 and 4**

$\Bbb{R}$  with  $(x,y)\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}$

$\Bbb{Z^x}$  with  $(x,y)\mapsto 1$

Are these groups? The first one is associative. but I cannot think of an identity element. For the second one I'm not so sure also, because it always maps to a constant element. Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: Trivially, $0$ is an identity element for problem 3.

Comment: An identity element is an $e$ such that $(e,y) \mapsto y$ for all $y$ in your group. So can you have one if $(x,y) \mapsto 1$ for all $x,y$?

Comment: No, you can't if it always maps to $1$. Would that be the correct answer?

Comment: I see that these are so simple questions, but I didn't have math for a very long time. Please excuse.

Answer (score 2):

In question two, $(x,y) \mapsto \frac{x}{y}$ is not actually associative.  You might want to check over your work.

For question three, as suggested in the comments, start by checking that $0$ is an identity.

For the last question, as also suggested in the comments, observe that an identity $e$ would satisfy $(2,e) = 2$.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake with the associativity of question two, thanks a lot for your hint. What is the best way to check for associativity? Just trial and error with actual values?

Comment: If the operation ($*$) is associative, you should be able to to transform $x*(y*z)$ into $(x*y)*z$ with some known rules. If it isn't, then just find a counterexample (three elements $x$, $y$ and $z$ for which it isn't true).

Comment: @Javiator what Leppala says is right.  Find a simple proof, or else find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in the solved problems.

For the first one check again if $x^{-1} = x - 4$ works.

In the second one, remember that the identity element must work both ways, $(x,e) \rightarrow \frac{x}{e} = x$ and $(e,y) \rightarrow \frac{e}{y} = y$.

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake, $x^{-1} = x - 4$ does not work. I'm do not know how to define the inverse element formally, but I do know that there exists one for every $x$.

Comment: Let $*$ denotes the operation : $(x, y) \mapsto x + y - 2.$ So given any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, we need to find a $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $x * y = e = y*x $. But this means $x + y - 2 = 2 = y + x - 2 \Rightarrow y = 4 - x.$